# Alterar funcionalidade WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, script

Como alterar esse script, para que ao invés dele pegar a imagem do diretório do WordPress, ele pegar a primeira imagem que existir no post.

O objetivo desse script é ao invés do tema buscar apenas imagens do diretório do WordPress, ele também use qualquer imagem que tiver no post.

Estou utilizando esse tutorial para tentar realizar essa aleração:

http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post/

Script do Tutorial:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content,     $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Esse pequeno trecho não sei onde uso:

```
<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
```

O script a ser modificado é esse:

```
<?php

/**
 * Containers for storing thumbnail types and its default sizes.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
$arras_image_sizes = array();

function arras_add_default_thumbnails() {

    $single_thumbs = arras_get_single_thumbs_size();
    arras_add_image_size( 'single-thumb', __('Single Post Thumbnail', 'arras'),             $single_thumbs[0], $single_thumbs[1] );
arras_add_image_size( 'sidebar-thumb', __('Sidebar Widgets', 'arras'), 36, 36); 

do_action('arras_add_default_thumbnails');
}

/**
 * Function to add image size into both theme system.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
function arras_add_image_size($id, $name, $default_width, $default_height) {
global $arras_image_sizes;

    $arras_custom_image_sizes = arras_get_option('custom_thumbs');

    // Check from options if a custom width and height has been specified, else use              defaults
if (isset($arras_custom_image_sizes[$id])) {
    $width = $arras_custom_image_sizes[$id]['w'];
    $height = $arras_custom_image_sizes[$id]['h'];
} else {
    $width = $default_width;
    $height = $default_height;
}

$arras_image_sizes[$id] = array(
    'name'  => $name, 
    'w'     => $width, 
    'h'     => $height,
    'dw'    => $default_width,
    'dh'    => $default_height
);

add_image_size($id, $width, $height, true);
}

/**
 * Function to remove image size into both theme system.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
function arras_remove_image_size($id) {
global $arras_image_sizes, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

unset($arras_images_sizes[$id]);
unset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$id]);
}

/**
 * Function to get image size's name, width and height, default or custom.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
function arras_get_image_size($id) {
global $arras_image_sizes;

return (isset($arras_image_sizes[$id])) ? $arras_image_sizes[$id] : false;
}


/**
 * Helper function to grab and display thumbnail from specified post
 * @since 1.4.0
 */
function arras_get_thumbnail($size = 'thumbnail', $id = NULL) {
global $post, $arras_image_sizes;

$wxh = arras_get_image_size( $size );
    $empty_thumbnail =  '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/thumbnail.png" alt="' . get_the_excerpt()
                                        . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '" width="' .     $wxh['w'] . '" height="' . $wxh['h'] . '" />';

if ($post) $id = $post->ID;

// get post thumbnail (WordPress 2.9)
if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) {
    if (has_post_thumbnail($id)) {
        return get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, $size, array(
            'alt'   => get_the_excerpt(), 
            'title' => get_the_title()
        ) );
    } else {
        // Could it be an attachment?
        if ($post->post_type == 'attachment') {
            return wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false, array(
                'alt'   => get_the_excerpt(), 
                'title' => get_the_title()
            ) );
        }       
        // Use first thumbnail if auto thumbs is enabled.
        if (arras_get_option('auto_thumbs')) {
            $img_id = arras_get_first_post_image_id();
            if (!$img_id) return $empty_thumbnail;

            return wp_get_attachment_image($img_id, $size, false, array(
                'alt'   => get_the_excerpt(), 
                'title' => get_the_title()
            ) );
        }
    }
}
return $empty_thumbnail;
}

/**
 * Function to retrieve the first image ID from post.
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
function arras_get_first_post_image_id($id = NULL) {
global $post;
if (!$id) $id = $post->ID;

$attachments = get_children('post_parent=' . $id .     '&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image');
if (!$attachments) return false;

$keys = array_reverse(array_keys($attachments));
return $keys[0];
}

function arras_get_single_thumbs_size() {
$layout = arras_get_option('layout');

if ( strpos($layout, '1c') !== false ) {
    $size = array(930, 375);
} else if ( strpos($layout, '3c') !== false ) {
    $size = array(465, 190);
} else {
    $size = array(620, 300);
}

return apply_filters('arras_content_width', $size);
}

/* End of file thumbnails.php */
/* Location: ./library/thumbnails.php */
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse script descrito da function 
catch_that_image ja pega a primeira imagem do post atraves do preg_match

Para exibir a imagem você vai usar o codigo abaixo dentro do seu tema, seja na pagina que exibe o post ou no loop

```
<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de se fazer isso, se você pegar o seu texto e a imagem que for a primeira for a thumbnail do post você pode fazer da forma 1, caso seja uma imagem no texto e não seja a destacada você pode realizar da forma 2

Forma 1:

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail() ?>
```

Forma 2:

```
<?php catch_that_image() ?>
```